# How to set the wal_level on AWS RDS Postgresql 13?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-13

After upgrading RDS to Postgres 13.1 our logical replication failed with the `connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 0)` error. When I checked the parameter group I could not find the option to set the `wal_level` anymore (should be `logical`). Does anyone know how to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical replication can be enabled by setting `rds.logical_replication = 1` and `shared_preload_libraries = pglogical` in the parameter group.

The `wal_level` does not need to be set explicitly.